# Multiply two textbox inside loop and display result on third textbox

Tags: javascript, php

This code will result for 10 lines of textbox1, textbox2, and textbox3. If I enter value in first line of textbox which is in loop1. for example   1  and 3 it will multiply and result is 3 . but then it will display the result in all loop. How can i make it only in loop1.?

Example

```
        QTY    PRICE   AMOUNT

line1    1        2      3
line2                    3
line3                    3
line4                    3
line5                    3
line6                    3
line7                    3
line8                    3
line9                    3
line10                   3
```

PHP HTML CODE

```
<?php for($x=1; $x<=10; $x++){?>
<tr> 
    <td><input type="text" name="qty<?=$x;?>" class="qty form-control" size="6"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price<?=$x;?>" class="price form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount<?=$x;?>" class="amount form-control"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

JS CODE

```
<script>
    $(".price,.qty").keyup(function () {
      $('.amount').val($('.qty').val() * $('.price').val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to address the correct amount field, for example by searching for the `.amount` class in the current row. You can also parse the name value to get the number so that you can look for the correct name attribute. And you should probably use arrays for your form element names to make that easier.

Comment: thats why i put in on class    and i give  unique names by putting the variable x inside the name of textbox.

Comment: Yes, but `$('.amount')` will address all amount inputs.

Comment: So how can I make it the it will have unique amount?  . I am not that expert on JS

Answer (score 2):

this will be much easy if you write separate for each event try this,

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".qty").keyup(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.amount').val($(this).val() *    $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val());
    });    

     $(".price").keyup(function () {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.amount').val($(this).closest('tr').find('.qty').val() * $(this).val());
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, although you should explain how and why this works and not just post code.

Comment: This code will Display same result in all lines.  for exaple  line1  1 and 3 = 3 line2 1 and 5 = 3   .. I try your code

Comment: event not working? try to put code inside $(document).ready()

Comment: same no result display

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(".price,.qty").keyup(function () {
        var curName = $(this).attr('name');
        var reqName = '';

        if (curName.indexOf("qty") != -1) {
         reqName = curName.substr(3);
        } else {
          reqName = curName.substr(5);
        }
        $("input[name='amount"+reqName+"']").val($("input[name='qty"+reqName+"']").val() * $("input[name='price"+reqName+"']").val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it .. I just change it instead of using Class I use ID  then put variable x inside the id and also put variable x on my JS

```
<?php for($x=1; $x<=10; $x++){?>
<tr> 
   <td><input type="text" name="qty<?=$x;?>" id="qty<?=$x;?>" class="form-control" size="6"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="price<?=$x;?>" id="price<?=$x;?>" class="orm-control" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="amount<?=$x;?>" id="amount<?=$x;?>" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>


$("#price<?=$x;?>,#qty<?=$x;?>").keyup(function () {
 $('#amount<?=$x;?>').val($('#qty<?=$x;?>').val() * $('#price<?=$x;?>').val());
});
```

Comment: Just try above code that i put right now . it's also working. And according to slandered. because on each user system short codes are working that is not sure.